# read load from csv file for PSS/E

Tags: python, csv, psse

I am trying to read CSV file that updates loads in PSS/E:
csv structure is as follows:

```
10004,10,10
10006,10,10
10007,10,10
10008,10,10
```

```
with open('1.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
       loaddatalst = row.split(',')
       loadbus = int(loaddatalst[0])
       loadid = '1'  
       loadp = float(loaddatalst[1])
       loadq = float(loaddatalst[2])
       psspy.load_data_4(loadbus, loadid, [_i, _i, _i, _i, _i, _i], [loadp, loadq, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

but I am getting this error:
loaddatalst = row.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Any advice?

updated code after Zach suggestion:

```
with open('load01.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
       loadbus = int(row[0])
       loadid = '1'  # or loaddatalst [x], x is position of load id in row
       loadp = float(row[1])
       loadq = float(row[2])
       psspy.load_data_4(loadbus, loadid, [_i, _i, _i, _i, _i, _i], [loadp, loadq, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: The row object is a list of strings; the reader has already split the line for you. So, just access the row by index to get at that row’s columns.

Comment: Thank you Zach, by referencing the row i was ablet to access it and write in PSS/E.

Comment: updated code in question after your suggestion